# LastAccessTime of the very last accessed File of an array of Folder

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-5.0

I'd like to get an overview of the latest accessed file per profile directory out of a list of profile directories and then write the result in a file.

**Given:**

A folder with a ton of profile directories in it. In every profile directory, there are more folders and files.

**Wanted:**

I need the date with the name of the profile directory of the latest accessed file of each profile directory within the parent folder.

**What I already have:**

With the following commands, the output file lists the last accessed file out of all files in the whole directory times the count of profile directories in the folder:

```
cd \\Servername\Patch\Profiles
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Directory
$folder | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1
} | Out-File "C:\Users\User-abc\Desktop\Log.txt"
```

So I tried to add the specific path for each profile folder within the parent folder to the `Get-ChildItem` command like this:

```
... ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem -Path ".\$folder" -Recurse |
    Sort-Object ...
```

I also tried to add a `.Name` to the `$folder` variable and to remove the `"` or put `'` instead of `"`, but nothing helped. I always get the response that there is no parameter found for the parameter `-Path`.
I also tried to remove the `-Path` parameter but let the `.\$folder` or even add a `[0]` or `[1]` to the `$folder` variable, but that also doesn't help.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's just an tying error. of cause I did write -Path, otherwise the PowerShell would have throughen an error like "no parameter "patch" found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Get-ChildItem` on the full path of the current object in the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem \\Servername\Patch\Profiles -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse |
    Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's what I already got.
I need to get the last accessed file of all of the profile directories of one common parent folder.

Comment: Ah okay, the $_.Fullname is the interesting part here I think. 
I'll try that tomorrow.
What exactly does that $_. thing even do?

Comment: Like I already said: it's the current object in the pipeline.

Comment: so I also could do a $folder.FullName in my case?

Comment: No, you can't. What gave you that idea? `$folder` is a list of all subfolders of your base directory. `$_` is a single folder at a time.

Comment: Thats it, now it works. Thank you :)

`Get-ChildItem $DirectoryPatch -Directory | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | select FullName, *time | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 } | Out-File $LogPatch`